# removeChildByTag: child not found

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Some breakpoints have pointed to the fact that this following line of code sends a `CCLog` that says `removeChildByTag: child not found`:

```
    CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, item3, nil];
```

The actual creation of `item1` and `item3` do not cause any unusual CCLOGs but the creation of the menu itself does. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place where CCMenu or CCMenuItem send a removeChildByTag message is in the CCMenuItem method `-(void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)index` which in turn is called by the initWithTarget and activate methods.

I suppose as long as your menu is working this is nothing to worry about.